# Is an unipotent matrix always diagonalizable? If yes, how to prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra

An unipotent matrix is a square matrix N such that
${\displaystyle N^{k}=1}$ for some positive integer $k$.

We can get $\lambda^k=1$ but it doesn't guarantee $n$ independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Where are you getting this definition of unipotent? The one I'm familiar is that $A$ is unipotent if $A-I$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** A matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ if and only if its minimal polynomial has distinct roots.

**Hint 2** If $N^k=I$ then the minimal polynomial of $N$ divides $X^k-1$.